# Animation on hover only works the first time

Tags: css, animation

I have a simple DIV with text in that animates on hover. The only problem is that it only does it once, if the user hovers over it again it does nothing until the page is reloaded.

Is there anything I can do so that it animates every time it's hovered over without the user having to refresh?

CSS

```
.animated2:hover {
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
-ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
-o-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-ms-animation-duration: 1s;
-o-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes tada {
0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1);}   
10%, 20% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotate(-3deg);}
30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);}
40%, 60%, 80% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-3deg);}
100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0);}
}

@-moz-keyframes tada {
0% {-moz-transform: scale(1);}  
10%, 20% {-moz-transform: scale(0.9) rotate(-3deg);}
30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);}
40%, 60%, 80% {-moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-3deg);}
100% {-moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0);}
}

@-o-keyframes tada {
0% {-o-transform: scale(1);}    
10%, 20% {-o-transform: scale(0.9) rotate(-3deg);}
30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);}
40%, 60%, 80% {-o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-3deg);}
100% {-o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0);}
 }

@keyframes tada {
0% {transform: scale(1);}   
10%, 20% {transform: scale(0.9) rotate(-3deg);}
30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);}
40%, 60%, 80% {transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-3deg);}
100% {transform: scale(1) rotate(0);}
}

.tada {
-webkit-animation-name: tada;
-moz-animation-name: tada;
-o-animation-name: tada;
animation-name: tada;
}
```

Comment: @ChristianVarga Please change above comment to answer.

Comment: @JustinJohn my comment might not be an answer, he might have set the fill mode for a specific reason, which would render my comment incorrect.

Comment: I'm using the CSS from animated.css & I have accepted all answers which have worked for me and helped me. There's no reason to be rude.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach your goal with using a little bit Javascript.

You can add the animation class (tada) on hover to your div where you want to have the animation.
Of course when you move out your mouse cursor you have to remove the animation class (tada).

I haven't tried the rotate but you can also make scale work without Javascript for sure.

For example:

```
.animated2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.animated2:hover {  
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
  -o-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05); 
}
```

Should work for scale everytime you move your cursor on a div.

Cheers.